# Is there a list of autoexpanded like [ask] for comments?

Tags: support, comments, magic-links

I did not know what this is called, the the title became bad.

But there are a few things in comments that get autoexpanded, like [ask], [mre], [help], [tour] etc. I assume there is a list somewhere for this, so my question is where is that list and what is this concept called?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting